# C# PropertyGrid Help area not refreshing upon resize/paint

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a problem where when the property grid is resized and repainted, the help area in the property grid doesn't seem to resize properly. I see that it retains the original size with which the grid was created and the remainder of the area remains dirty (in the pic the dirty area is from the background Window (Bk Win).

[image: PropertyGrid]

Any idea how I can make sure that the help area is also getting resized properly so that the dirty area gets repainted properly?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the controls in the DocComment don't get updated automatically (bug in .NET?)..but here is a quick solution..

```
 
private void PropertyGrid_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Control control in (sender as PropertyGrid).Controls)
    if (control.GetType().Name == "DocComment")
    {
      FieldInfo fieldInfo = control.GetType().BaseType.GetField("userSized",
        BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      fieldInfo.SetValue(control, true);
      control.Width = (sender as PropertyGrid).Width;
      foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
      {
          ctrl.Width = control.Width;
      }
      return;
    }            
}
```